# How to run VHDL Components in a sequential fashion?

Tags: components, vhdl, sequential

I'm making a simple TicTacToe game (computer vs user) in VHDL and the code is almost finished, but there is something that I can't figure out how to handle it.

Overall there are three main modules, computer move based on the current grid, grid status that takes in which cell to be filled either by computer or by user, a main module that retrieves the grid from the grid module and handle these components as well as the user move.

So, in this main module, I have a Component that sends the move (either by computer or user) to the grid module and in return updates its current grid Signal in this main module, then the second component (computer move) takes in the grid status (which is the Signal) and make a move based on that. Therefore, this also needs to get sent to the grid module for it to be updated. However, this doesn't really work in action when it comes to functioning in this order.

In a nutshell, my question is, how may I go about updating this main Signal in the order of the Components execution or more generally, how may I have a Signal be updated by a Component that needs to become the input of another Component respectively?

Thanks for your help.

**Edit**

Here is part of the main module code

```vhdl
ENTITY currentstate IS
  PORT (to_occupy_cell : IN TO_SELECT;   --user choice
        start : IN STD_LOGIC;     --initialize the grid
        by_user : IN STD_LOGIC;   --how to fill the grid (X or O)
        difficulty : IN STD_LOGIC;     --difficulty
        winner_state : OUT INTEGER RANGE 0 to 2;     --who is the winner? 
        currentgrid : OUT GRID (1 TO 3, 1 TO 3));  --outputs status of the grid after compmove to be displayed
END currentstate;
---------------------------------
ARCHITECTURE statearch OF currentstate IS
  SIGNAL comp_occupy : TO_SELECT;
  SIGNAL grid_status : GRID (1 TO 3, 1 TO 3);

  COMPONENT grid IS   -------saves the grid status
    PORT (to_occupy_cell : IN TO_SELECT; start : IN STD_LOGIC; by_user : IN STD_LOGIC; currentgrid : OUT GRID (1 TO 3, 1 TO 3));
  END COMPONENT;

  COMPONENT compmove IS
    PORT (current : IN GRID (1 TO 3, 1 TO 3); dif : IN STD_LOGIC; compsel : OUT TO_SELECT);
  END COMPONENT;
BEGIN

  U1: grid PORT MAP (to_occupy_cell, start, by_user ,grid_status);

  U2: compmove PORT MAP (grid_status, difficulty, comp_occupy);
```

Here is the grid module

```vhdl
ENTITY grid IS
  PORT (to_occupy_cell : IN TO_SELECT;   --user choice
        start : IN STD_LOGIC;     --initialize the grid
        by_user : IN STD_LOGIC;   --how to fill the grid ( X or O)
        currentgrid : OUT GRID (1 TO 3, 1 TO 3));  --outputs status of the grid after compmove to be displayed
END grid;
---------------------------------
ARCHITECTURE gridstatus OF grid IS
BEGIN
    PROCESS (to_occupy_cell, start)
    VARIABLE temp_grid : GRID (1 TO 3, 1 TO 3);
  BEGIN
    IF (start = '1' AND start'EVENT) THEN
      temp_grid := (others => (others=>0));
    END IF;
    IF (by_user = '1') THEN 
      temp_grid(to_occupy_cell(0), to_occupy_cell(1)) := 1; 
    ELSIF (by_user = '0') THEN 
      temp_grid(to_occupy_cell(0), to_occupy_cell(1)) := 2;
    END IF;

    currentgrid <= temp_grid;
  END PROCESS;
END gridstatus;
```

And entity of the computer move module

```vhdl
---------------------------------
ENTITY compmove IS
  PORT(current : IN GRID (1 TO 3, 1 TO 3);  --takes in the grid status
       dif : IN STD_LOGIC;     --difficulty
       compsel : OUT TO_SELECT);
END compmove;
---------------------------------
```

So, what happens is that, the Signal grid_status should automatically be updated first by the user move and then when it is updated it gets piped into the `compmove` module for the computer to decide which cell to fill. Afterwards, the grid_status should get updated again. Also, '1' is the user move, '2' is the computer move in the grid.

Hope this clears what I'm after.

(image referenced from [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfdkz.jpg) added)

[image: sequential components]

**EDIT 2:**

Thanks to the help of David and fru1tbat I could actually get it to work! Turns out I had missed making compmove sensitive to grid_status. 
However, now it is only working for the first round but not the second round if the user selects another cell. Below are the updated codes:

Main module (currentstate)

```
ENTITY currentstate IS
  PORT (to_occupy_cell : IN TO_SELECT;   --user choice
        start : IN STD_LOGIC;     --initialize the grid
        by_user : IN STD_LOGIC;   --how to fill the grid ( X or O)
        difficulty : IN STD_LOGIC;     --difficulty
        winner_state : OUT INTEGER RANGE 0 to 2);     --who is the winner? 
END currentstate;
---------------------------------
ARCHITECTURE statearch OF currentstate IS
  SIGNAL occupy_to_grid : TO_SELECT;
  SIGNAL comp_occupy : TO_SELECT;
  SIGNAL user_move : STD_LOGIC;
  SIGNAL grid_status : GRID (1 TO 3, 1 TO 3);

  COMPONENT grid_ IS   -------saves the grid status
    PORT (to_occupy_cell : IN TO_SELECT; start : IN STD_LOGIC; by_user : IN STD_LOGIC; currentgrid : OUT GRID (1 TO 3, 1 TO 3));
  END COMPONENT;

  COMPONENT compmove IS
    PORT (current : IN GRID (1 TO 3, 1 TO 3); by_user : IN STD_LOGIC; dif : IN STD_LOGIC; compsel : OUT TO_SELECT);
  END COMPONENT;

BEGIN

  U1: grid_ PORT MAP (occupy_to_grid, start, user_move,grid_status);

  U2: compmove PORT MAP (grid_status, user_move, difficulty, comp_occupy); 

  PROCESS(comp_occupy, to_occupy_cell)
  BEGIN
    IF to_occupy_cell'EVENT THEN
      occupy_to_grid <= to_occupy_cell;
      user_move <= by_user;
    END IF;
    IF comp_occupy'EVENT THEN
      occupy_to_grid <= comp_occupy;
      user_move <= '0';
    END IF;
  END PROCESS;
END statearch;
```

The grid_ module

```
ENTITY grid_ IS
  PORT (to_occupy_cell : IN TO_SELECT;   --user choice
        start : IN STD_LOGIC;     --initialize the grid
        by_user : IN STD_LOGIC;   --how to fill the grid ( X or O)
        currentgrid : OUT GRID (1 TO 3, 1 TO 3));  --outputs status of the grid after compmove to be displayed
END grid_;
---------------------------------
ARCHITECTURE gridstatus OF grid_ IS
BEGIN
    PROCESS (to_occupy_cell, start)
    VARIABLE temp_grid : GRID (1 TO 3, 1 TO 3);
  BEGIN
    IF (start = '1' AND start'EVENT) THEN
      temp_grid := (others => (others=>0));
    END IF;
    IF (by_user = '1') THEN 
      temp_grid(to_occupy_cell(0), to_occupy_cell(1)) := 1; 
    ELSIF (by_user = '0') THEN 
      temp_grid(to_occupy_cell(0), to_occupy_cell(1)) := 2;
    END IF;

    currentgrid <= temp_grid;
  END PROCESS;
END gridstatus;
```

Initial part of compmove

```
ENTITY compmove IS
  PORT(current : IN GRID (1 TO 3, 1 TO 3);  --takes in the grid status
       by_user : IN STD_LOGIC;   --to only gets triggered when user selects a cell
       dif : IN STD_LOGIC;     --difficulty
       compsel : OUT TO_SELECT);
END compmove;
---------------------------------
ARCHITECTURE comparch OF compmove IS  
BEGIN

  PROCESS(by_user, current)
    VARIABLE tempsel : TO_SELECT := (0,0);
    VARIABLE occ_count : INTEGER := 0;
    VARIABLE unocc : INTEGER := 0;
  BEGIN
    IF (dif = '0' AND current'EVENT AND by_user = '1') THEN
      --------------bunch of codes here
```

It is almost there, I believe just a small change perhaps in the sensitivity list of compmove would do the trick for it to retrieve the updated grid_status correspondingly, because currently after the first round it doesn't take in the updated grid_status and comp_occupy remains unchanged!

Comment: It's difficult to understand what it is you are asking.  If possible do you think you could provide a diagram of the hardware noting the signal that is in question as well as some of the relevant declarations?

Comment: Sure, updated the post with more info.

Comment: I'm afraid I still am not terribly clear on what it is you are asking, could I ask you for a diagram?  (if you are trying to take two signals into a single input you must merge the two signals first... e.g. or them together)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Does this make sense? [link](http://i.imgur.com/ZWBMazJ.jpg)

Comment: The way your entity/architecture pairs are currently written looks like they guarantee `currentgrid` is atomically written, received.  They'll be separated by one delta cycle.  Without understanding `compmove` is it possible a concurrent event on `difficulty` is causing your problem? And of course the other possibility is that you have an error somewhere (e.g.`compmove`).

Comment: Thank you David, I'm not so great in VHDL generally so there might be some mistakes. Actually, compmove by itself works just fine which works sequentially in a Process, "difficulty", simply toggles an algorithm in compmove. The issue is that when grid_status is changed by the grid Component, the changed grid_status is not passed to compmove, so its output (comp_occupy) remains unchanged!

Comment: I couldn't help but wonder whose VHDL analyzer you are using as well. After genning up some missing type declaration in an undisclosed package I found a name conflict between the component declaration of `grid` and the type `grid` (you could renamed the component/entity and arch target or direct instantiate `grid)`. Notice `by_user` is missing from the process sensitivity list in grid.  This last sounds like you're problem.  P1076-201X is talking about a keyword `all` in sensitivity lists for the analyzer to get it right automagically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your process that writes to the `grid_status` signal only accepts input from the user (`comp_occupy` doesn't connect to anything in your main module) so how can the computer update the grid with its move? What you seem to need is an input (or set of inputs) to the `grid` module that connects to `comp_occupy`, and a modified process in `gridstatus` which monitors both players and updates the grid from either source.

**(edit)**

On further consideration, I realize your intent may be to have a single input to the `grid` module which adds a move for either player. You appear to want to use events on `by_user` to update the grid, but I don't see the logic that switches `by_user` to create the sequence. You seem to need something like (in your main component):

```
process (to_occupy_cell, comp_occupy)
begin
  if by_user = '1' then
    occupy_to_grid <= to_occupy_grid;
  else
    occupy_to_grid <= comp_occupy;
  end if;
  by_user <= not by_user; -- on input from either source, alternate user for next input
end process;
```

Then map `occupy_to_grid` to `grid` instead of `to_occupy_cell`. This assumes that the new value of both 'occupy' signals is assigned on the same delta (or else `by_user` will flip back and forth unexpectedly), so if that's not the case, you will need to modify accordingly.

Let me know if this is close to what you're looking for.

Comment: Great suggestion! It really helped. Nonetheless, there is still a small issue which I updated the first post with. Would you mind having a look at it and perhaps spot which part is not functioning correctly that it doesn't work for the second round.

Comment: It would help to see your stimulus/testbench, and possibly your code for `compmove`. I ran a quick sim, and it worked fine. Note that if the AI moves to (0, 0), that won't trigger an update, since that's probably the initial value of `compsel`, and therefore there is no signal event generated (same for the player, probably). You may want to add another (binary?) signal that explicitly tells the algorithm that a move has been issued.

Comment: Hmmm, wondering why it isn't working for me, compmove code is pretty long and simple and only does decision making, in the end it applies the move to the compsel signal. I have some feelings IF statement condition is not really correct. For testing it, first I set Start = 1, dif = 0, do a single run, then specify a cell in to_occupy_cell and set by_user = 1, this works fine for the first run. Afterward, I only change to_occupy_cell and expect it to work after another run (or shall I change by_user myself too?). Fortunately the grid starts from (1,1) so a value of (0,0) is not valid anyway!

Comment: Sorry - forgot your grid range is 1 to 3. It depends, then, on how you define your `TO_SELECT` type. If you use an integer subtype that's limited in range to (1 to 3), you will have the same problem. As long as your signals of type `TO_SELECT` don't initialize to a valid grid position, you should be ok.

Comment: TO_SELECT is this: TYPE to_select IS ARRAY (0 to 1) OF INTEGER RANGE 0 TO 3; So, I believe this is not problematic either. I just can't now spot where possibly the bug is :(

Comment: Not sure. Without seeing more code, I have two guesses: something in `compmove` (possibly a variable that you're not re-initializing at the beginning of the algorithm, which is keeping its value from the previous process iteration), or something in the way you're simulating. To test your code, I threw together a rudimentary testbench which sets `start`, waits a little bit, sets `to_occupy_grid`, wait a little bit more, sets `to_occupy_grid` again, and waits again (other inputs are pre-initialized and do not change). In my simulation, the computer responds both times, as expected.

Comment: You are the man!!! Great hint, again the problem was indeed in the compmove *facepalm* ! It was my misinterpretation that I thought declaring a variable like `VARIABLE tempsel : TO_SELECT := (0,0)` would be same as initializing a variable to default (0,0) every time the Process runs, but it wasn't like so! Thanks again, it all seems to be good now!

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be missing `by_user` from the process sensitivity list in grid:

```
process (to_occupy_cell, start)      -- Add by_user to sensitivity list
    variable temp_grid : grid (1 to 3, 1 to 3);
begin
    if (start = '1' and start'event) then
        temp_grid := (others => (others=>0));
    end if;

    if (by_user = '1') then 
        temp_grid(to_occupy_cell(0), to_occupy_cell(1)) := 1; 
    elsif (by_user = '0') then 
        temp_grid(to_occupy_cell(0), to_occupy_cell(1)) := 2;
    end if;

    currentgrid <= temp_grid;
end process;
```

The only thing that fit from your description was a missing event trigger the process.  The idea being by_user isn't concurrent with any other input.

I also found a name conflict between `grid` in the component declaration in `currentstate` and the undeclared package containing the type declaration for type `grid` with two different VHDL analyzers.  (After making up a package and type declarations for `to_select` and `grid`).

### Addendum

I added a test bench, and also hooked up `grid_status` to the returned `currentgrid` in `currentstate` so it would show up at the top level.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use work.foobat.all;

entity  test is
end entity;

architecture foo of test is

    component currentstate is
        port (
            to_occupy_cell: in      to_select;   --user choice
            start:          in      std_logic;     --initialize the grid
            by_user:        in      std_logic;   --how to fill the grid (x or o)
            difficulty:     in      std_logic;     --difficulty
            winner_state:   out     integer range 0 to 2;  --who is the winner? 
            currentgrid:    out     grid (1 to 3, 1 to 3)
        );  --outputs status of the grid after compmove to be displayed
    end component;


    signal to_occupy_cell:  to_select;
    signal start:           std_logic := '0';
    signal by_user:         std_logic := '1'; 
    signal difficulty:      std_logic := '0'; 
    signal winner_state:    integer range 0 to 2;
    signal currentgrid:     grid(1 to 3, 1 to 3);

begin

DUT:
    currentstate
        port map (
            to_occupy_cell => to_occupy_cell,
            start          =>  start,
            by_user        =>  by_user,
            difficulty     =>  difficulty,
            winner_state   =>  winner_state,
            currentgrid    =>  currentgrid     -- grid_status
        );

STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 1 sec;
        to_occupy_cell <= (2,2);    -- center
        start <= '1';               -- write 1 to gridstatus(2,2);
        wait for 1 sec;
        to_occupy_cell <= (1,1);    -- corner
        start <= '0';               -- no separate delta cycle event
        wait for 1 sec;
        wait;

    end process;

end architecture;
```

So the two sets of grid values show below are `grid_status` (surfaced) and `current` on the `compmove` port.  From what I can tell, `grid_status` gets to `compmove`.

[image: grid_status gets to compmove]

This was done with ghdl and gtkwave.  ghdl handles array signals in waveforms.  The waveform trace image is larger than it will likely appear in your browser, you can open it in a separate tab/window or otherwise view it larger.

The values shown for the two versions `grid_status`/`current` appear identical.

Note there are three events on `grid_status`, the initial event which writes to leftmost row and column in the grid.  I'm not sure why `to_occupy_cell` doesn't show up properly in the waveform, it doesn't show up as an array but does show the events.  It's likely a result of how I declared the `to_select` type.

The initial or default transaction, the `start'event and start = '1'` transaction and to_occupy_cell transition (concurrent with `start` = `0`).

Anyway, the point is that `grid_status` gets to `compmove`.

Comment: Actually by_user gets updated at the same time that to_occupy_cell gets changed, because when the user selects a cell to be occupied by_user also gets toggled on by it, therefore, the PROCESS should still get triggered by the current sensitivity list, shouldn't it? Oh yeah sorry about that, ignore the Grid typo, I just replaced the name when wanted to paste the code here with another sensible name, but as you noticed it conflicted with the Grid type. Is what I'm trying to achieve, shown in the diagram, possible at all?

Comment: Well, without devolving into more of twenty questions, you're not likely to get an answer here without more description, either of what actually happens (not just what doesn't happen) or more than 1/3 of your design description.  Without seeing the design specification containing current_state, or you showing waveforms the problem you are having isn't readily apparent.

Comment: This is all the code here except the compmove which I highly doubt it is the problematic one (I also made it sensitive to by_user). The question/problem is all about that single diagram in the first post! Suppose grid_status is 0 at the initialization, the grid component output would change the value of grid_status let's say to 1. At the same time grid_status is an input of compmove Component, but what compmove receives is 0 not 1! And this is what I'm after, I want compmove Component to retrieve the updated grid_status. Would it help if I send you all the code? :S

Comment: See Addendum in the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough explanation, as you said before, indeed there was an issue in the compmove sensitivity list which I fixed it somehow, however, it now only works for the first round! Updated the first post.